# How do I calculate the distance between X and Y in php?

Tags: php, distance

I created a script to measure distances between villages in the game Travian
My code works correctly, but only with a specific partition. Because there is a fifth element with ($X1, $Y1, $X2, $Y2) which is the size of the map

Example:
if all ($X1,$Y1,$X2,$Y2) numbers Less than 100 like ( 99 , 1 , -85 , -55 , 0 , 13 ... etc ) AND the map size is 200 (Max 200,-200) It works properly ..

This is the code:

```
<?php
$distance    =  round(sqrt(pow(bcsub($X1, $X2,1),2)+pow(bcsub($Y1,$Y2,1),2)),1) ;
?>
```

```
==the result of==
$X1 = 66
$Y1 = 55
$X2 = 44
$Y2 = 33
is (31.1)
```

But if the map size is 200 (Max 200,-200) and :-

- I choose a number greater than 100
- one of the numbers is negative

the result will be not correct

```
==the result of==
$X1 = 101
$Y1 = 160
$X2 = 190
$Y2 = -194
is (365)
And the correct one is (100.6)
```

http://travian.kirilloid.ru/distance.php#cc=101,160,190,-194&srv=1.45&size=200&spd=7&art=1

**the point at (199, 199) is adjacent to (-199, -199) .. and the distance Between them is (4.2) .. in my code Gives me (562.9) ...**

How do I solve this problem please :(

Comment: I seem to remember this from basic algebra: a²+b²=c². In other words if you know x (the horizontal) and y (the vertical) you can compute the hypotenuse which is the distance between them. square root (x²+y²)=hypotenuse

Comment: @PHP Guru: That's Pythagoras theorem. For this formula to work, angle of the shortest sides need to be 90 degrees

Comment: What is the size of the map when your formula is correct?

Comment: I assume the map is 2 dimensional? If it's round like the earth then it will not work. If it's 2 dimensional then you can operate on a cartesian coordinate system of x and y and pythagorean theorem works just fine.

Comment: the point at (199, 199) is adjacent to (-199, -199) .. and the distance Between them is (4.2) .. in my code Gives me (562.9) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked calculator uses a different formula from Pythagoras.

```
var d = Math.hypot(
    delta(this.state.cc[0], this.state.cc[2], this.state.size),
    delta(this.state.cc[1], this.state.cc[3], this.state.size)
);
$('distance').innerHTML = d.toFixed(3).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');
```

```
function delta(c1, c2, size) {
    return (c1 - c2 + (3 * size + 1)) % (2 * size + 1) - size;
}
```

Source: http://travian.kirilloid.ru/js/distance.js?a

---

In PHP, that would be:

```
<?php

$X1 = 101;
$Y1 = 160;
$X2 = 190;
$Y2 = -194;
$size = 200;

function delta($c1, $c2, $size) {
  return ($c1 - $c2 + (3 * $size + 1)) % (2 * $size + 1) - $size;
}

$d = hypot (
    delta($X1, $X2, $size),
    delta($Y1, $Y2, $size)
);

var_dump($d); // float(100.64790112069)
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you ... the code works perfectly .